# Firefox streaming two cameras

Tags: javascript, firefox, navigator

I have a small app which prompts the user for camera permissions. I have two connected cameras so I get two prompts and I get to select which camera goes to which stream (there's a dropdown in the prompt). However, I doesn't seem to work anymore: I still have 2 streams with different IDs, but I only get one prompt and both streams show the same camera.

This is my code:

```
function handleSuccess1(stream) {
  console.log('stream1', stream);
  video1.srcObject = stream;

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(handleSuccess2).catch(handleError);
}

function handleSuccess2(stream) {
  console.log('stream2', stream);
  video2.srcObject = stream;
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.error(error);
}

// constraints object is just audio: false
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(handleSuccess1).catch(handleError);
```

Did something change in the browser API? Maybe I just made a change in the code that I don't recall, but in any case, it doesn't prompt for the second camera anymore, but it does give me 2 streams with different IDs. Any ideas how to get the second camera prompt working again?

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need the second prompt, ask permissions once and then grab the streams from the devices you want directly:

```
async (e) => {
  // first ask for permissions
  await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
  // then grab the list of all devices
  const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  // pick only input ones
  const inputs = devices.filter( (device) => device.kind.endsWith( 'input' ) );
  // stream them all, on their own 
  inputs.forEach( startNewStream );
};

async function startNewStream( device ) {
  // request a stream from a particular device
  const deviceType = device.kind.replace( 'input', '' );
  const constraints = {
    [ deviceType ]: { deviceId: device.id }
  }
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( constraints );
  // do whatever you wish with this stream now
  // ...
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lw0v1f72/

Ps: You are of course not forced to loop over all the devices and can just [build a select yourself from the list of devices](https://jsfiddle.net/pzy5oru3/).

Comment: I've tried this solution, but it doesn't work for me. I get prompt again, where I select the camera (I'm working on Firefox). I select one of the cameras and that camera streams ok. Then I try console logging both streams. The first one is fine, the second has an error: `constraint: ""
message: "Failed to allocate videosource"
name: "NotReadableError"`
​

Comment: That error means there is a problem with your camera. Can you connect to it when you select it from the first prompt? What when you try from an other browser?